# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a huge problem with debugging in visual studio 2017. It started to happen all at once and I don't understand why. I can not debug, all the time I am having famous 'the breakopint will not currently be hit' message.

I am working on MVC project - I've checked if .PDB files are in the bin folder -> they are, for every project. I have aslo followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b?page=2&tab=active#tab-top), but nothing helped.

What else can I try? I've checked that my configuration is in debug mode, I've unchecked 'enable just my code' option and do other things suggested in the post. But, still no success. If I check Debug - Windows - Modules, it's empty. Why is it not loading any assemblies for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What really solved the problem:
- in VS studio I was running application in IIS express. I've also had IIS installed, which is completely different instance. One of my links was localhost:3554 - but that was pointing to IIS, not IIS express port. I've changed port number in hyperlink and all was good.
- about not working references in VS2019 - I've just deleted .vs folder.