# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this file

Tags: c++, debugging, cuda

I have a problem to debug a cuda kernal. However, the breakpoints in kernal function are never hitted. I tried to delete this project and re-generate using CMake, but it still not work.
The kernal code is as follows:

```
__global__ void testKernel(int val)
{
    printf("[%d, %d]:\t\tValue is:%d\n", \
        blockIdx.y*gridDim.x + blockIdx.x, \
        threadIdx.z*blockDim.x*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x, \
        val);
}
```

I think the problem is not related with kernal code but with configurations of this project. Because this kernal can be debugged in CUDA Samples projects.

I use `Debug`->`Windows`->`Modules` and find that my target `.lib` is not loaded. When I select `CUDA Thread`, the `Break Mode` shows:

> You app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. onley native runtime code is executing).

Comment: Is this in a .dll? It's possible that the program has not loaded the dll yet - that would result in this error. If so, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b). Also, it's possible your source code is out-of-date with the compiled code. Try recompiling, perhaps

Comment: Sometimes the compiler optimises out what it considers redundant code. So placing a break point there probably won't be  hit. This happens when a function is inlined at runtime.

Comment: @alteredinstance It's a .lib. I've tried the solution according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top), the .lib is not loaded because it's generated by `nvcc` complier.  The problem still exist even though I deleted this project and used cmake to re-generate this project.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `-g` is missing when compile `.cu` file using `nvcc` compiler.
The original `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` in CMakelists.txt is:

> SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;)

After correction:

> SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}; -g; -G; -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;)

Now, we can use Nsight to debug the kernal function.