# Getting "the breakpoint will not currently be hit" after upgrade to .net core 3.0 from 2.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

[image]

Not able to add the debugger/ breakpoint after done the upgrade of .net core 2.0 to 3.0. It's working for version 2.0. Tried diff solutions still not working

Comment: If you add a new controller and actions, does same issue occur in new controller? Besides, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b) discussed similar issue, you can refer to it.

Comment: Yes, still not working.is this some VS configurations issue? but it's working for the .net core 2.0 version code. Really need help on this.