# How to enable debugging in VS 2022?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2022

I have just installed VS 2022 Community edition.

I have loaded Xamarin project in it. I can put debug points in the files, but debugger does not fire at that point.

So, I cannot debug the project.

Anyone can assist me here please what settings required in VS 2022.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been

Comment: @HansPassant on that question, debug points cannot be set. while here, I am able to set debug points where debugger does not stop.

Comment: Couple of questions: 

What is your build configuration? (maybe it could be set to release, and then VS won't produce pdbs which allow you to debug)

Which project are you trying to set breakpoints in? (Shared, iOS, Android, UWP)

Comment: @JohnTownsend I am trying with Android project having build configurations as Debug and AnyCPU.