# How to fix this issue "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2022

> Note: Right now I am converting from vs 2019 to vs 2022
> due to setting differences, I am unable to solve this issue.
> [Please click here for Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2hAr.png)

> I also check this setting but due to the setting difference, I am unable to fix this issue.
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262865/10988372

> I want to solve this issue in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: It might be helpful for you to read this answer to this question: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-the-source-1/962935

Comment: Ok let me check

Answer (score 0):

Your project has not been build properly.Click on the app solution and select rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for your time. but your answer is not meaningful for me.

Comment: I do this whenever I have such a problem  rebuild or I delete cashe Visual Studio

Comment: I have already applied all solutions then I placed a question on StackOverflow.