# Library not loading while debugging main project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

I have 3 projects:

1. `Xamarin forms`
2. `.NET Core(backend)`
3. .`NET Standard Library`

The library is connected to both projects. When I work with a `Xamarin` project I have no problem debugging a library project, but when I work with a `.NET Core` project I get the message

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

[All the methods described here - I tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been)

What should I do so that I can debug the library connected to it while debugging a project on `.NET Core`?

P. S. Initially, the library was created as a solution with the `Xamarin`.

Comment: What did you get when you tried the most voted answer?

Comment: @shingo This library is not there, it is not loaded there, but the pdb. is created.

Comment: Not there? Try to print `typeof(CLASS).Assembly.Location` to see where the library is. `CLASS` is any class from your library.