# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document. VS 2022 .NET 6

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core, breakpoints, visual-studio-2022

Breakpoints don't work in my projects. On every breakpoint I have such message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
> for this document.

I don't have any loaded symbols for my project in module tab.
I'm using **.NET 6 and VS 2022.** The project was initially created with .Net Framework and I've upgraded it to .NET 6
I've already tried to clean and rebuild the whole solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remedy "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been)

Comment: Need more information to reproduce your problem, or you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been) for the solution.

Comment: Solutions from your link don't work for VS 2022

Comment: Maybe you can [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help find the solution