# Visual Studio Community 2022. Breakpoint not hit in Blazor WebAssembly (Mud Blazor) Application

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

In my solution Visual Studio Community 2022, In one solution, I have different projects (class library, Web API and one Blazor Web Assembly). On Startup there are two projects

1. WebAPI
2. Blazor Web Assembly

I am using Mudblazor in Blazor Web Assembly project.
I have put different break points in different projects and all projects run in Debug mode. All the break points are hitting well except in Blazor project. I am getting following information on break point.
[image: Information of break point in Debug mode]

I have looked for a solution from a number of websites but found no solution. I also went through the following post but no benefit:
[How do I remedy "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been)
One more thing to share is that during solution execution I cannot find project name in
Debug -> Window -> Modules
I will be grateful, If someone please suggest a useful solution. Thanks

Comment: There are many possible factors that result in this issue. From the point of view of project settings, you can try to set project as default [Startup Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/a1awth7y(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  or clean/rebuild your project or delete  your breakpoints and set again. From the point view of specific project ` blazor webassembly `,it may has to do with your project code when using some class or method .You can provide minimal reproducible example that can help others to test and give  more accurate workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 7 console applications and 2 WebAssembly projects. I have just changed Optimize code setting as Release and breakpoints are getting hit.

[image]

I don't know the logic behind it but it works. I will go through as it is for the time being as project's deadline is approaching too fast.