# Can't debug some subproject in microservice architecture

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-5, visual-studio-2022, debug-symbols

I have problem with debugging repository which consists of few subprojects, I add them as a reference projects, and if I add one, everything works just fine, but if I add 2 or more, then debug files (.pdb) are not creating for all of them but only for one. With project should everything ok, because it works on my colleges environment. I use VS2022. I should add that other projects from the same collection I can debug normally.
Screens from my VS:

breakpoint cant be hit
[image: breakpoint cant be hit]

options build -> optimize code -> off

[image: options build -> optimize code -> off]

debugging -> general settings
[image: debugging -> general settings]

modules -> symbol status
[image: modules -> symbol status]

I followed instruction from this answers, but until now there is no result:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Finally a solution was find. It was resolved by adding additional project reference from another repository. After this debug symbols were created in correct location and were uploaded successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).