# Attaching a windows process to a .NET Core worker service project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging

I have a windows service using workers services in .NET Core 6.

I would like to know if it is possible to attach the process of my service to my project on visualstudio in order to be able to debug it.
With .NET Framework services, this works perfectly.

But with .NET Core worker services when I attach my service process I get this message: The breakpoint will not be reached for the moment. No symbol has been loaded yet.

I think I've read that in .Net Core this isn't possible, but I was wondering if there were any tricky ways of doing it.

Thanks,

Comment: I know this is for .NET Framework but it could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried it and it doesn't help :/