# How to change xUnit testing project from being non-user to user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, xunit.net

For some reasons, my testing project is considered non-user code according to the debug Modules. It's also optimized when it's built for Debug. As a result, the symbols are not loaded and all break points in the testing project are skipped. I have tried the solutions s[How do I remedy "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top):

1. Set project build as for debug
2. Manually load from the Modules
3. Tried different options with the process to attach.
4. Tried to change the property for the project (but VS 2022 is different from that the above link suggests)
5. Deleted cache, clean, re-build
6. Made sure the project is not excluded from loading symbols

Comment: You're trying to debug a test by finding it in the Test Explorer and running it there, not by hitting F5 / the main run button, right?

Comment: Did it used to work and suddenly stop working, or have you not been able to get a debug build working yet?  Sometimes debugging file versions can get "sticky" and don't properly overwrite during a rebuild. Do a Clean, then in your solution folder do a search for "obj" and delete any "/obj" folders, then do a search for "bin" and delete any "/bin" folders and only the "/bin" folders and their contents. (Don't delete anything  like the "/objects", folder from a .git folder!  After manually cleaning, do a Rebuild and check again.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes I was debugging it from the test explorer. I just tried hitting F5 it still skips the breakpoints.

Comment: @StevePy I tried that and still not working. It did work before, but I have been poking around with the cofig and settings with the testing project because I had trouble  hitting breakpoints in a multi-threads situation. I think I might have changed some settings and now the testing project is considered non-user code.  It seems if I can't change it to user code, the symbols won't get loaded.

Comment: I just noticed it's also optimized when the setting for the project is debug.

Comment: That config looks a little strange, Optimize should be False for Debug, and typically True for Release. You can see/change those settings by bringing up the project properties. Right-click on the project file in the solution explorer and select "Properties". Under the "Build" selection there is an "Optimize Code" tickbox. You also want as a minimum the Define DEBUG constant set to True as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is helpful, I found that in the .csproj file there are some conditional settings that reverse the settings from the GUI. How these extra settings get there remains a puzzle, but the lesson maybe that the GUI cannot fully control the settings and the .csproj file can override it.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people