# Metadata file facades dll could not be found CSC error

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Visual Studio 2013. When I am compile/running my project I am getting Error

> "Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
> Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\ .NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\ *.dll'
> could not be found projectPath\CSC ProjectName".

I have refereed [Metadata file '.dll' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found)

I tried all the solutions in above link but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the wrong path in your references.  On my machine I have a different path to the Facades directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\*.*

Double check your \ separators.

Comment: Looks like the stack overflow editor is eating some of the back slashes... so some back slashes have to be doubled up.

Comment: And you have the last backslash after Facades\\*.dll  ?

Comment: yes i have it.  "Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\ *.dll' could not be found projectPath\CSC ProjectName
 "

Comment: I need to give space before " * " in above path else the slash disappears.

Comment: Why is it looking for *.dll?  Typically references are added one at a time?  Does the directory actually exist on your system?

Comment: You might have to upload the project file that is causing this.