# I am getting a Metadata file "filename" could not be found error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Ok, so here is the problem, I have an application that works fine. However, when I build the project I sometimes get the error:

> Metadata file 'C:\Users\myUsername.KSS_WINNT\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\NewRDT\NewRDT\bin\Debug\NewRDT.dll' could not be found.

Other times I get the warning:

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
>   "NewRDT". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this
>   reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

I have the dll in my References, and like I said the application runs fine when I just press the Start button, but still would like to find out what is giving me the error and warning. Not sure what code I could post to help out, but if anyone needs anything just let me know and I will be happy to post it, just not sure what you would need to look at.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Metadata file '.dll' could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I get error about missing metadata i just clean solution then rebuild it.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't help. It happens every time I clean and rebuild. The clean always succeeds fine, but the build will give the error or warning.

Comment: Well, something there fixed it. I didn't know there was such a thing as build order. You learn something everyday. Thanks a bunch man.