# Xamarin.Forms failed to compile android project with "Droid.Resource.Attribute" does not contain a definition for "actionBarSize"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project, and it worked just fine until I updated my Xamarin Studio Community to latest 5.10.3 (build 51) and updated Xamarin.Forms to 2.2.0.31

When I compile my android project, it showed me

```
"mynamespace.Droid.Resource.Attribute" does not contain a definition for "actionBarSize"
```

I did not change anything after upgrade and it works before, I know some others faced the same problem like me when I search on google, seems no one asked this in stackoverflow yet so I would like to get some help here.

Comment: compiled with API 23

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete Bin and Obj folders in project folder
2. Delete contents of `C:\Users\{your username}\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips`
3. Rebuild project
   *This will take a while because Xamarin will re-download the required files. It should work after it's done.*

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug listed [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39910). There are different workarounds about this, please try:

[Failed to use Android Support Library v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055924/failed-to-use-android-support-library-v4/36759115)

[Creating a Hello World in Visual Studio with Xamarin Forms Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347287/creating-a-hello-world-in-visual-studio-with-xamarin-forms-fails)

[Xamarin cross-platform (portable class) project compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820545/xamarin-cross-platform-portable-class-project-compilation-error)