# Have an "'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'" error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Was trying to debug an empty app and got "'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'" error. I have reinstalled android SDK's.

```
    public static void UpdateIdValues()
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize = global::L1NQ.Droid.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize;
    }
    public partial class Attribute
    {

        static Attribute()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Attribute()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (and various more) after create a new .forms project (shared) with VS2015 Update 3 RC.
To the JDK 7, I had installed the version:
Java SE Development Kit Update 55

After I have downloaded and installed
**Java SE Development Kit Update 79**

from: [Download JDK 7 - Update 79](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

and rebooted my machine
this problem (an various further problems) has gone.

Comment: Does it supports JDK 8 Update 40??? , B'coz I have 8 Update 40, still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't know - in my case, I was able to resolve the problem with exactly the version, I wrote above...

Comment: @NiravMadariya "It is essential to install the 32-bit version of the Java JDK even if you're using 64-bit Windows. It is also important that v1.7 of the Java JDK is installed (although it is fine to have 1.8 or newer installed at the same time)." https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_Java_SDK_(JDK)

Answer (score 2):

This error can have also 2 other reasons.

1. If any of your images named contains "-"  (dash) in android
   project.
2. if you are using xlab, latest stable xlab version is not
   compatible with latest XF version. you find more details and
   solution [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1125). It is suggested to use XLabs.Forms 2.2.0-pre05

Comment: TO ANYONE NOW VIEWING THIS PAGE:  This answer, which was not applicable when the question was asked, solved my issues.  The latest stable builds of Xlabs and Xamarin.Forms were incompatible (as of 11/1/16).  Once I updated to XLabs.Forms 2.2.0-pre05 through the NuGet Package Manager (there is a checkbox to show available prerelease builds), my elusive problem was solved.  I had been stuck for days, so this seems like a HUGE BUG to me.  Idk how this is the first I've read about it.  I'm shocked that Xlabs has not updated the stable version yet. This needs more upvotes! Thanks a lot @batmaci !

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files at C:\Users{your username}\AppData\Local\Xamarin and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Removed all Xamarin Google Play Services nuget packages.
- Reinstall those packages which i need.

Once i tried to install packages again nuguet asked me to change Compile API to level 24.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your axml twice in my case i write `android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"` this line in my axml file but in my drawable there is no file whose name id  "ic_action_content_new"