# Xamarin Forms ERROR: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day. I was creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable application that enables the User to CRUD record of an Employee and was able to run it many times. But when I run it again, there's an error saying

***'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'***

It is located on the Android part of my program.
[image]

This line of code causes it and I don't have a clue why.

```
    public static void UpdateIdValues()
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize = global::XamarinFormsDemo.Droid.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize;
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: From my experience could say that _Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize_ is not the error that cause the problem. `actionBarSize` located in generated file, so before that error you have some other critical issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have an "'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238846/have-an-resource-attribute-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-actionbarsize)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347287/creating-a-hello-world-in-visual-studio-with-xamarin-forms-fails