# Missing files not missing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My solution is not building. Visual Studio 2015 is griping about missing dlls, of solution projects, that are not in fact missing. The solution is building fine on other folk's machines. Are there specific local factors that could cause this? Is there something I can reset to get back to a clean environment?

[image: screenshot of error]

Text of an error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Metadata file      'C:\NotilusTNE\Sources\NotilusWeb\Agile\Dev\NotilusWeb\Dimo.Notilus.Data.Mappers\bin\Debug\Dimo.Notilus.Data.Mappers.dll' could not be found Dimo.Notilus.Interfaces.MobileApp   C:\NotilusTNE\Sources\NotilusWeb\Agile\Dev\NotilusWeb\Dimo.Notilus.Interfaces.MobileApp\CSC
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions suggested in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found

Comment: It is hard to read the txt of the error, could you copy 1 of them and provide the textual error instead?

Comment: Are you sure your solution is compiling in the correct order?

Comment: Is the reference to the missing dll, a file reference or a project reference?  If it is a file reference, do you have the same file/folder structure as the other folk's?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this I think, by deleting all binaries in my lib folder a clean set from tfs. This tip came from a colleague who'd had the same issue. Difficult to know if this answer will be useful.