# VS2017 Metadata file '.dll' could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, build-error

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2017, I am unable to build my project. Visual Studio 2015 still works when pointing at the exact same project.

this is the build errors I get `Metadata file '******.dll' could not be found`

I've already tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/17723774/3511012 with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked the issue down to a specific NuGet package that has not yet been updated for visual studio 2017. (Baseclass.Contrib)

It isn't yet registered as having updates available through the nuget package manager, but you can manually update using the nuget console and running this command `Install-Package Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output -Version 2.3.0-vs20172`