# Error: Xamarin bin and obj folder empty and build failing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I'm building a Xamarin project for Android and IOS on Visual Studio 2019 but my `bin` and `obj` folder when I compiled where empty all of a sudden.

It gives an error saying `Metadata file '.dll' could not be found`

I tried:

- Deleting those folders and then clean and recompile.
- Deleting hidden `.vs` folder.
- Unchecking and then checking debug build on properties.

Please help because I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: After deleting bin and obj folder, just restore nuget package and build again. May be it will resolve your problem

Comment: NOTE: In the future, when you solve your own problem, instead of editing the question to add the solution, please add "Your Answer" below. Thank you. (In this case you might not be able to do so, if this question gets closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes thank u, it is the answer that I posted

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error and in my case what worked was to clean, unload and reload the projects.

[Here is the solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46968258/18568045)