# Unable to build Xamarin project - missing file and Error CS0006

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

> Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode' to type
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode'.

which also says : Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\Linda\Lindos\Lindos\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Lindos.dll' could not be found   Lindos.UWP

I was looking at [Metadata file '.dll' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found)
nothing works, seems like all anything related to XAML has broken.

Comment: Others types of project working normally ?

Comment: yes, keep pointing to 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
xml could be very sensitive but it doesn't look like spelling