# .NET 5.0 publish gives CS0006 dll could not be found for .NET Standard 2.0 dependency

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a .NET 5.0 project, `ProjectA`, which depends on a .NET Standard 2.0 project, `ProjectB`. I can build and run the .NET 5.0 including its dependency without issues. The two projects are stored in the same root folder, and relying only on default configurations, the resulting libraries end up in

```html
ProjectB\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ProjectB.dll
ProjectA\bin\Release\net5.0\ProjectA.dll
```

as expected.

If I use the VS Pro 2019 v16.8.6 UI to publish the .NET 5.0 project, however, using the publish profile

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>{{ my-url }}</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>{{ my-guid }}</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I end up getting the error that

> CSC(0,0): Error CS0006: Metadata file 'ProjectB\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\win-x64\ProjectB.dll' could not be found

The build that precedes the publish still builds `ProjectB` as expected, but still leaves it in `netstandard2.0`, as opposed to `netstandard2.0\win-x64` where the publish step is looking. I can add a build step to manually copy the built `ProjectB` files to the `win-x64` but that's pretty clunky.

Is there a way to tweak the publish configuration so it looks for the dependency in the right place?

The closest related StackOverflow post is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537269/error-metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found-csc-when-publishing), in which we encounter the same issue in a different context, and in which the solution was to get rid of `TargetFramework` in the publish profile. Doing so does not resolve the issue in my case.

Interestingly, `dotnet publish -r win-x64` (from .NET SDK (5.0.104)) figures out where to look for the `ProjectB` files, so that works, but seems unable to use the `pubxml` above (cf. [also this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332343/dotnet-publish-with-ppublishprofile), for which none of the given answers work here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Visual Studio (from 16.8.6 to 16.9.2) fixed the issue, so presumably this was simply a bug in the earlier version of Visual Studio.