# Metadata file could not be found

Tags: blazor, c#-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'F:\BlazorWebAssembly\BlazorProject\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\ref\BlazorProject.Client.dll' could not be found  BlazorProject.Server    F:\BlazorWebAssembly\BlazorProject\Server\CSC   1   Active**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkOL5.png)

Also, I delete the obj, bin folder, and rebuild the project but did not fix that. Are you know How to fix that case. Please help me...

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found) and check your configuration of visual studio,

Comment: The order of events may be important. Have you tried the following? (1) Clean solution in your IDE; (2) Close all instances of the IDE; (3) Delete the obj and bin folders in _all_ your project's folders; (4) Reopen your IDE and your solution; (5) Build.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will be fine when you restart your computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

As per [Link from Yiyi You above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found), the response by Heinz Kessler solved it for me.
The problem was that there were build errors that were only visible in the Output Window.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem at publish time
and many search in site but not found answer
after 30 minutes tried i've re-new my publish profile
after that my problem has solved

Answer (score 1):

I had tha same issue. I removed the weatherforcast model and controller, but i forgat to remove the weatwerforcast page at the Client/Pages. Make sure your remove the weatherforcast stuff everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I right-clicked on the ptoject I got the error for, and selected "Build".
The error is gone.