# After Update Visual Studio 2022 (Mac) to version 17.0 (build 7303) Xamarin Projects not working - Error CS0006: Metadata file *.dll could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Today I updated my Visual Studio 2022 (17.0 build 7303) for Mac and after I trying to start my xamarin project I receive error:

```
/Users/pizhev/Projects/HydroMeteoAnalyzer/HydroMeteoAnalyzer/HydroMeteoAnalyzer.Android/CSC: Error CS0006: Metadata file '/Users/pizhev/Projects/HydroMeteoAnalyzer/HydroMeteoAnalyzer/HydroMeteoAnalyzer/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/ref/HydroMeteoAnalyzer.dll' could not be found (CS0006) (HydroMeteoAnalyzer.Android)
```

I check here: [Metadata file '.dll' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found) but on Visual Studio on Mac when **I right click on the solution and click options -> Go to Configurations** I not have any checkboxes..

What can I do on `Configurations` window on mac ?

### [image: Configurations]

I try this method but without positive result for me:

1. I delete all bin and obj folders in all projects.
2. Open solution -> clean solution -> Build solution.

---

After update on Visual Studio for Mac to version 17.0 (build 7303) I try to create a new empty project on xamarin and when I try to start I receive the same error.

How can I fix this error ?

Please, help guys.. I need to fix this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, I've got it fixed by enabling the `Build with MSBuild on Mono` checkbox in the `Solution Properties > Build > General` section. (I had disabled it previously to build a .NET6 project in that solution).

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link which solved the problem for me after a long search: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/7355
I added this to the assembly project file which was referenced by the other projects
Once I added this, I started to see the ref folder getting created and the dependent projects started to build.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If after deleting the folders - bin, obj and hidden folder .vs the problem is not solved -> Uninstall Visual Studio 2022 and Install Visual Studio 2019. After installation, everything it work normally.