# Monodevelop debugging asp.net with xps Metadata file error

Tags: asp.net, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to run the simple asp.net application created by Monodevelop but i get a strange error

```
CS0006: Metadata file `/path_to_myhome/c' could not be found
```

Actually i don't know how to fix it. I've done several search on the internet without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329142/metadata-file-could-not-be-found-error-when-building-projects

Comment: That question is unrelated.